# I just don't get it, why bother using SASS if it compiles to CSS?

Tags: sass

So I am on the fence about learning SASS. I still don't get it. Why bother if I can write CSS and understand it and it works.

Why learn to raise chickens if all I want is the egg?

It seems as though the SASS would take longer to figure out then just writing the css.

I can use variables in CSS3. I also don't understand why you would write `.foo {padding: $width/2;}`
I have to figure out what padding I want then figure out the mathematical equation to write it. I just want to write padding: 12px; and be done...

Please enlighten me on WHAT Makes SASS better? quicker? easier?

thanks -

Answer (score 2):

Advantages are like this
You can separate your sass files into modular areas. For instance

```
SASS
  1. tools (put bourbon or bitters here)
  2. basics (body, links or common things)
  3. modules (reuasable stuff. Boxes, cards, etc)
  4. layouts (your containers, footers, headers etc)
```

In doing this you can easily find where the CSS is that you may want to change. There are several youtube videos that discuss how to make modular sass directorys.

You can use variables. Suppose you have a color that is used several times in a CSS file. SASS allows you to change one variable and that would change all instances of that usage. $red: #ff0000 is an example of a variable. When you use it, just use

```
color: $red
```

Mixins are functions that you can use and easily create a small amount of sass that will convert into large amounts of CSS.

I suggest watching videos on youtube to learn it. You wont be sorry. Especially learn modular usage like SMACSS

Here is a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTBaQ2DcGUk&t=3s) to a vid that will help you

Answer (score 0):

Sass is an extension of CSS that adds power and elegance to the basic language. It allows you to use variables, nested rules, mixins, inline imports, and more, all with a fully CSS-compatible syntax. Sass helps keep large stylesheets well-organized, and get small stylesheets up and running quickly, particularly with the help of the Compass style library.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to stick with CSS, there is nothing wrong with that. (My understanding is that) People like SASS because they can type is with variables and such and it will then be converted into regular CSS. So yes, it does basically the same thing, but the improvements come as writing it, which is faster and more efficient. People that use SASS like that they don't have to write the same or similar things, they can instead just use SASS and get it converted to CSS which is faster than writing it, now I am just a SASS beginner, so please don't read into my thoughts that much, some of this may be not 100% correct, but it is my understanding. In my opinion, you should look into SASS and maybe try it a little, if you find it is more efficient and you like it more, stick with it, but if you decide it just isn't for you, then just stick with CSS.